# How to instruct Emacs auto-capitalize-mode to automatically lowercase any word that follows e.g. or i.e.?

Tags: emacs, org-mode, capitalization, capitalize

Emacs auto-capitalize-mode misinterprets the words `i.e.` and `e.g.` to signify the end of a sentence, and, accordingly, erroneously capitalizes any word that follows them.

Does anyone have a function that can be called by entering, say, `eg` or `ie`, that will insert the characters `e.g.` and `i.e.` and then automatically lowercase whatever word gets typed next?

Bonus: Do the same thing... for ellipses.

Comment: When using `i.e.` or `e.g.`, there should be a comma after each -- this should avoid any confusion about it being an end of a sentence.  You can check it using the regexp from the function `(sentence-end)` and `M-x re-builder`.  Although there are different views, this one supports my position so I chose that one -- :) -- http://english.stackexchange.com/a/16215

Comment: `auto-capitalize.el` is not part of GNU Emacs. My suggestion would be to ask the maintainer of that library (Kevin Rodgers) about this. But you might also try setting `sentence-end-double-space` to non-`nil` (the default value), and then use two spaces to separate sentences.  A guess would be that `auto-capitalize.el` might respect `sentence-end-double-space` to DTRT wrt `e.g.` etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to your .emacs:

```
(setq auto-capitalize-predicate
      (lambda () (not (looking-back
           "\\([Ee]\\.g\\|[Ii]\\.e\\)\\.[^.]*" (- (point) 20)))))
```

Remember that the I in i.e. will be capitalized to I.e if your
auto-capitalize-words variable is set to contain “I”.

`(setq auto-capitalize-words '())` This sets it to nothing.

Here’s a version that also deals with ellipses:

```
(setq auto-capitalize-predicate
      (lambda () (not (looking-back
           "\\([Ee]\\.g\\|[Ii]\\.e\\|\\.\\.\\)\\.[^.]*" (- (point) 20)))))
```

But you might want to look into some abbrev magic that turns three periods into a unicode ellipsis instead. It's up to you.

Comment: Thank you, this works perfectly! Question: Is there a way to keep this list in a plain text format so I can add to it more easily? The reason I'm asking is because I wanted to add the word "vs." to the list (e.g. "good vs. evil") but I couldn't get the regexp correct with all the slash escaping. It would be easier if the code for the actual list looked something like this: 
`(setq *auto-capitalize-exceptions* (list "e.g." "i.e. " "vs." "..." "- [ ] "))`

Comment: Someone could write a program to transform such strings into suitable regexes but I haven't seen one.

Answer (score 0):

From auto-capitalize.el:

```
;; To prevent a word in the `auto-capitalize-words' list from being
;; capitalized or upcased in a particular context (e.g.
;; "GNU.emacs.sources"), insert the following whitespace or
;; punctuation character with `M-x quoted-insert' (e.g. `gnu C-q .').
```

I use it and it is a comfortable approach.